# Table with a tick, horizontal text and multiple vertical and horizontal columns

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment, multirow, multicolumn

I am trying to draw a table like this using IEEE trans template. I don't even know where to start. Any suggestions?[image]

Comment: You can start with www.tablesgenerator.com and improve from there.

Comment: Thanks. But I am not sure if it can rotate the contents of the table as shown.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the online [LaTeX Table Generator](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/) with a few clicks you can do this:

[image]

This is the best I can do in the site. Then moving the generated code to LaTeX, we can do a few modifications to get the code below.

#### Update

I incorporated Mico's suggestion of the `\extrarowheight`, I also added a `\phantom{.}` after the `NB` to get a gap between the `B` and the horizontal rule.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow} % For multirows
\usepackage{amssymb} % For the checkmark
\usepackage{graphicx} % For the rotation
\usepackage{array} % To enlarge the vertical space of the table's contents
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[]
 \setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}
 \centering
 \caption{My caption}
 \label{my-label}
 \begin{tabular}{l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|}
  \cline{2-11}
  \multirow{2}{*}{}                            & \multirow{2}{*}{Suggestions} & \multicolumn{9}{c|}{Other side}   \\ \cline{3-11} 
                                             &                   &   &  &   &   &   & \rotatebox{90}{NB\phantom{.}} &   &   &   \\ \hline
  \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\multirow{4}{*}{\rotatebox{90}{Based}}} &                   &   &  &   &   &   &    & \checkmark & \checkmark &   \\ \cline{2-11} 
  \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{}                       & Your Answer       &   &  & \checkmark &   & \checkmark & \checkmark  &   &   & \checkmark \\ \cline{2-11} 
  \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{}                       &                   & \checkmark &  &   & \checkmark &   &    &   &   &   \\ \cline{2-11} 
  \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{}                       &                   & \checkmark &  &   &   &   &    &   &   &   \\ \hline
 \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Which produces:

[image]

Now you can play changing the `l` alignment characters to `p{}` and get different column widths, but this I'll leave up to you ;)

Comment: Big thanks. Hopeful others would also benefit in the future

Comment: +1. One more suggestion: Load the `array` package and issue the instruction `\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}`.

Comment: Thanks Mico where should I include the instruction?

Comment: Just after `\begin{table}` if it's only for this one. In the preamble for all tables.

Comment: Thanks to everyone. I guess a little modification have been made to the table. Just wondering how was 'NB' rotated upwards. Would like to benefit with regards to this one also.

Comment: @Abdulhameed My bad, I changed in the picture but not in the code. To rotate something in LaTeX, use `\rotatebox{angle}{something in LaTeX}`. You have to `\usepackage{graphicx}`. I updated my answer with Mico's suggestion and fixed this issue.